# Is it possible to merge unit test code coverage result with UI test code coverage on XCode?

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm trying to get a consolidated report of code coverage report by merging unit testing code coverage result with UI testing results. Is it possible to do this ? Are there any tools to merge them?